# .NET : Double-click event in TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

I would like to intercept the event in a .NET Windows Forms TabControl when the user has changed tab by double-clicking the tab (instead of just single-clicking it).

Do you have any idea of how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MouseDoubleClick event of the TabControl seems to respond just fine to double-clicking.  The only additional step I would do is set a short timer after the TabIndexChanged event to track that a new tab has been selected and ignore any double-clicks that happen outside the timer.  This will prevent double-clicking on the selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, MouseDoubleClick, as suggested by Jason Z is only firing when clicking on the tabs and clicking on the tab panel does not do anything, so that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing the TabControl class and adding your own DoubleClick event?